# Sort custom field in Kibana

Tags: logstash, kibana

I am using Elasticsearch, Logstash 2.1, Kibana 4 as a logging platform.

In Logstash's config I add field (for example field People) :

```
filter{
   muate{
      add_field => { "People" => "Some unique name variable"}
   }
}
```

I can see column People in Kibana Discover tab, that's OK. But I cannot sort Kibana's table of logs by field "People". What should I set up in Logstash's config to sort people in Kibana? Thanks.